# Pypi - any resource (website/script etc) to find popularity metric for a user to identify a relevant package

Tags: python, pypi

I wish to identify the "most appropriate" Python library to use for my problem. I have encountered this task/requirement so many times that I thought that perhaps I can ask it here.

Let's say I wish to implement a "Kalman Filter" (a popular computational routine across disciplines) in my application and naturally, use existing professional libraries. One metric/criterion I like to know about before investing a whole lot of time (reading documentation etc.) is some measure of it's popularity index by the community. (maybe a rating like github stars, or download count like what Mathworks' fileexchange website provides).)

The search string "Kalman Filter" on PyPi yielded about 15 results, leading much confusion to which one should I invest my time on.

Is there a way (maybe a python/shell script?) available to obtain some insight into a package/library's peer-review/quality/download stats from the python package archive https://pypi.python.org based on a user's search string?

Comment: Though I can see where you're coming from, this isn't a signal processing question. Also, I'd argue that if you pick your math primitives by popularity, you might be doing something wrong, if the *whole* set of things you're picking from is of size ~15.

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow. Try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/